# Can't parse a website link from a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've created a script in python with selenium to scrape the website address located within `Contact details` in a website. However, the problem is there is no url associated with that link (I can click on that link, though).

> How can I parse the website link located within `Contact details`?

```
from selenium import webdriver

URL = 'https://www.truelocal.com.au/business/vitfit/sydney'

def get_website_link(driver,link):
    driver.get(link)
    website = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[ng-class*='getHaveSecondaryWebsites'] > span").text
    print(website)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    try:
        get_website_link(driver,URL)
    finally:
        driver.quit()
```

When I run the script, I get the visible text associate with that link which is `Visit website`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Element with "Visit website" text is a `span`, that has `vm.openLink(vm.getReadableUrl(vm.getPrimaryWebsite()),'_blank')` javascript and not actual href.
My suggestion, if your goal is to scrape and not testing, you can use solution below with `requests` package to get data as json and extract any information you need.
Another one is actually click, as you did.

```
import requests
import re

headers = {
    'Referer': 'https://www.truelocal.com.au/business/vitfit/sydney',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                  'Chrome/73.0.3683.75 Safari/537.36',
    'DNT': '1',
}
response = requests.get('https://www.truelocal.com.au/www-js/configuration.constant.js?v=1552032205066',
                        headers=headers)
assert response.ok

# extract token from response text
token = re.search("token:\\s'(.*)'", response.text)[1]

headers['Accept'] = 'application/json, text/plain, */*'
headers['Origin'] = 'https://www.truelocal.com.au'

response = requests.get(f'https://api.truelocal.com.au/rest/listings/vitfit/sydney?&passToken={token}', headers=headers)
assert response.ok
# use response.text to get full json as text and see what information can be extracted.

contact = response.json()["data"]["listing"][0]["contacts"]["contact"]
website = list(filter(lambda x: x["type"] == "website", contact))[0]["value"]
print(website)

print("the end")
```

Comment: This is surely the approach I wanted to stick to If I knew about it in the first place @Sers. Could you help me understand how did you dig out that link?

Comment: You can find good information about requests [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/). Feel free to accept answer, if it solves your problem, https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Comment: Yeah, I know the rules and I'll surely accept your solution. I wanted to know how did you find out the url you have used. I tried with chrome dev tolls but doesn't seem to find it. Could you help me on that? Thanks.

Comment: @MITHU To find open devtools, go to network tab, reload page, than you can see all file download. Find one with response you need, get headers and params from Headers section.